# Ordenar dados em dataframe pandas pela frequência de repetição de cada elemento

Tags: python, pandas, classificação, dataframe

Eu tenho um dataframe e quero organizar os dados pela frequência de aparecimento de cada elemento. Do que mais se repete para o que menos se repete, para criar um ranking. Eu quero que a organização seja feita a partir das colunas `uf` e `tipo_acidente`

```
acidentes2020 = pd.read_csv('https://arquivos.prf.gov.br/arquivos/index.php/s/jdDLrQIf33xXSCe/download', compression='zip',encoding='iso8859-1', sep=';')

ranking2020 = acidentes2020[['uf', 'tipo_acidente']]
```

Comment: você quer apenas sortear as observações? Se sim, veja o método `sort_values`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html Caso você queira agrupar os valores antes de ranquear, use `groupby`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: desculpe, minha pergunta foi equivocada. Eu quero ranquear mesmo. Por exemplo: quero que mostre o `tipo_acidente` que mais ocorreu para determinada `uf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em detalhes:

### Carregando biblioteca

```
import pandas as pd
```

### Criando DataFrame de teste

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1,2,2,1,3]})

print(df)

    A
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   1
4   2
5   3
6   1
7   1
8   2
9   2
10  1
11  3
```

### Criando coluna com frequências

```
df['frequencia'] = df.groupby('A')['A'].transform('count')

print(df)

    A  frequencia
0   1           5
1   2           4
2   3           3
3   1           5
4   2           4
5   3           3
6   1           5
7   1           5
8   2           4
9   2           4
10  1           5
11  3           3
```

### Ordenando por frequência

```
df1 = df.sort_values(by='frequencia')

print(df1)

    A  frequencia
2   3           3
5   3           3
11  3           3
1   2           4
4   2           4
8   2           4
9   2           4
0   1           5
3   1           5
6   1           5
7   1           5
10  1           5
```

**Nota 1**: usar o `ascending=False` para ordenar em ordem decrescente

**Nota 2**: usar o `inplace=True` para não ter que atribuir o resultado a outro DataFrame